# Implementing URLRewriter.Net gives a Reference Exception

Tags: c#, .net, module, url-rewriting, nullreferenceexception

After following the instructions [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/URL-Rewriting-ASP.NET.aspx)

**How To Implement URL rewriting with UrlRewriter.Net?**

I'm getting a Referenece Exception -->

---

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfiguration.Load() +109
   Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfiguration.get_Current() +216
   Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule..cctor() +47

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule' threw an exception.]

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +1051
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +111
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.Create() +39
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpModulesSection.CreateModules() +164
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +28
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +729
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +298
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107

### System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +289

I have added the   tag because I have read that this error most of the times pops up when you don't have the rewriter section specified in your web.config.
So what can be the problem now?
I'm trying to run this on an IIS 6.0 (windows 2003) server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module won't be able to run on IIS 6.0 since the URLRewrite module 2.0 is only available for IIS 7.0 as an extension.